# IE 6 PNG problem

Tags: internet-explorer-6, png

Having trouble getting the top left background suitable in IE 6, this is the JS im using, it works for everything else on the page but not this :(

http://www.naomisalsi.com

```
DD_belatedPNG.fix('#navigation, .logo, #contenttop, #content, #contentbottom, #flowerbottom, body');
```

Answer (score 1):

IE6 breaks for transparent PNG. Maybe try this [one](http://homepage.ntlworld.com/bobosola/) ...

Comment: I think looking at the function's name, and the working bottom right image, a fix is already being used.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try giving the body an id

```
<body id="page_body">
```

and use that ID in the list:

```
DD_belatedPNG.fix('#navigation, .logo, #contenttop, #content, #contentbottom, #flowerbottom, #page_body');
```